# copyfile option from listview item pops up Copy dialog because of the array, any alternatives to do copy only once?

Tags: powershell

The abstracted code:

```
for($i=0;$i -le $filecount;$i++){
    $name = $droper.Items.Item($i).text
    $copytemp = Split-Path $name.ToString() -leaf -resolve
    $pasteitem = $datepath+"\" + $copytemp
    $setclipboard = [System.Windows.Clipboard]::SetFileDropList($name)
    #$t= [System.IO.File]::copy(,$true)
    $t = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::CopyFile($name, $pasteitem, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption]::AllDialogs)
}
```

This works perfectly, except that for every loop for every file it copies the dialog appears.

Any way to have this copy dialog to copy all the file in array or loop only once?

Comment: I added a missing bracket in the For loop. Is there something missing from this code or was that an accident in copying?

Comment: ya it was a copy error, thank you!!

Comment: $droper is a listview box which contains filepath which dropped to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.uioption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you tell `CopyFile()` to show all dialogs (`[Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption]::AllDialogs`) then it most certainly will do as it's told. Call `CopyFile()` without that option if you don't want the dialogs:

```psh
$t = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::CopyFile($name, $pasteitem)
```

or (better yet), do it the PoSh way:

```psh
for($i=0; $i -le $filecount; $i++) {
  $name = $droper.Items.Item($i).text
  Copy-Item $name "$datepath\"
}
```

You can add [`Write-Progress`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849902.aspx) to the mix if you want the overall progress displayed:

```psh
for($i=0; $i -le $filecount; $i++) {
  $name = $droper.Items.Item($i).text
  Write-Progress -Activity 'Copying ...' -Percent ($i*100/$filecount) -Current $name
  Copy-Item $name "$datepath\"
}
```

If you need a graphical overall progress bar you'll probably need to build it yourself. Jeffrey Hicks published an example [here](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/02/18/progress-bar-to-a-graphical-status-box.aspx).

```psh
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text   = 'Copying ...'
$form.Height = 100
$form.Width  = 400
$form.StartPosition = [Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

$progress = New-Object Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progress.Name  = 'progressBar1'
$progress.Left  = 5
$progress.Top   = 40
$progress.Value = 0
$progress.Style = 'Continuous'

$drawingSize = New-Object Drawing.Size
$drawingSize.Width  = 360
$drawingSize.Height = 20
$progress.Size = $drawingSize

$form.Controls.Add($progress)

$form.Show()
[void]$form.Focus()

for($i=0; $i -le $filecount; $i++) {
  $name = $droper.Items.Item($i).text
  Copy-Item $name "$datepath\"
  $progress.Value = [int]($i*100/$filecount)
  $form.Refresh()
}

$form.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, I certainly had this way, but I need to display the dialog to users when the copy happens(feedbacks from users), Hence I used copy file dialog than the write progress(only displayed in powershell console). (the Form window hangs and user is not sure what happens).

Comment: Thank you Ansgar,It works when the form loads for the first time, but next time it erros out...Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'Form'."

Comment: @ARP You need to instantiate a new `Form` object after you closed the old instance.

Comment: Ok , will mark this post as answered for now, I prefer to have the copy dialog which also verifies the file presence on the destination.Thanks Ansgar for all the help!!

Comment: @ARP `Copy-Item` should throw an exception if copying fails. Also, you could use `Test-Path` to verify the presence of the destination file afterwards.

Comment: Ya that would hang the APP again due to the path (I have server spread around the globe).